# JavaScript-library-based Project Organization

Tags: javascript, project-organization, google-closure

I'm very new to the JavaScript library world. I have used JS by itself before to create a mini social network but this is the first time I use a JS library and I really don't know how to go about this.

I'm planning to use Google Closure and I'm really not sure how I should go about organizing the code. Should I put everything in one file since it's a web app and should have one screen? Should I separate the code to many chunks and put them in different files? Or should I put different dialogs (like settings) in a separate page and thus a separate file?

Like all programmers I'm a perfectionist so please help me out with this one, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Closure, you can use the closure compiler. I'd recommend multiple js files that are compiled into a single resource by the compiler. You'd reference that single js file in your html, so you wouldn't have to link to all of them.

Then, since you have multiple JS file, you can organize them in a logical way that will help you separate logic from UI from communications, etc.  Also, if you're writing unit tests (JsUnit) it will be easier to write one test file per js file.

Answer (score 1):

Depends...
What I do is add all my code in one file(librarys are always in different files) and then even though some of it wont be used, there will be no need to add multiple scripts to the page. If you have 20 files with script, it can be very confusing knowing which one to use.